# How do we apply the ORDER BY and LIMIT,OFFSET Clauses to DAO.fetch(query) in cn1-data-access?

Tags: sqlite, codenameone

DAO.fetch(query) allows us to get a collection of entities from the sqlite database that meets the query condition. query can be a map or string []. How can we specify ordering with the ORDER BY clause and also how do we apply the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses or do we have to default to db.execute(query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently ORDER BY, LIMIT, and OFFSET clauses aren't supported.  It wouldn't be hard to add.  Please file an RFE.

Alternatively it wouldn't be difficult to add this in your own DAO subclass.  You can see how fetch(query) is implemented [here](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/blob/master/src/ca/weblite/codename1/db/DAO.java#L426).